# Is it okay to fetch market data from platform A and trade on platform B? (Forex)

Tags: fx, market-data

I am currently trading forex on capital.com but since they don't offer tick data I am considering to fetch the tick data from polygon.io and then trade on capital.com.

Though I am wondering if this is a bad idea?
I am still new to quantitive trading so I would love some advice.

Comment: This related question should give you some insights: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75260/backtesting-on-one-exchange-while-trading-on-another/75279#75279